# How do I stop my sound/music from playing in another frame?

Tags: java, netbeans

I used the following code to play a song but it's 11 minutes long so how can I stop it?

This code is in a jFrame 1. How can I make it stop in a jFrame 2?

```
                        InputStream test =getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("musics/menu.wav");
                        AudioStream Audio = new AudioStream(test);                        
                        AudioPlayer.player.start(Audio);
```

I tried chaning `AudioPlayer.player.start(Audio);` to `AudioPlayer.player.**stop**(Audio);` but with no success.

Comment: Stop the `AudioPlayer` before you switch JFrame's.

Comment: @WhyCry I can't, because I have around 4 Jframes that are in the menu. I just want to stop it when it goes in-game.

Answer (score 1):

Normal java naming conventions say that variables usually start with lower case letters, so `Audio` in `AudioStream Audio = new AudioStream(test);` may be misinterpreted for a class, not your local variable.

I think [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/sun.audio/AudioPlayerstopInputStreamarg0.htm) link can help you with the `stop` method, if that's the code that isn't working.

If you're not having trouble with the stop method nor variable names, then I suggest you use a separate class to hold your AudioStream objects and make them static, so any class in the same package can access it.

Your class would look something like this:

```
public class AudioHelper {
    static InputStream test = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("musics/menu.wav");
    static AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(test);                        

    public static void play() {
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
    }

    public static void stop() {
        AudioPlayer.player.stop(audio);
    }
}
```

And you can access its methods like this, no matter what JFrame you're in:

```
AudioHelper.play();
AudioHelper.stop();
```